# WPF How to reset/refresh bound viewmodel when utilizing Prism/Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm in the process of trying to wrap my head around how Prism and Unity work within WPF but currently have been roadblocked by a simple task. Possibly I have a misunderstanding on how it works.

How does one refresh a bound viewmodel?

I have a wpf application using Prisms RegionManager to load up a user control:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" x:Name="mainContent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
```

Inside my user control I have a field for a user to fill out with a submit button and clear button (Abbreviated user control contents)

```
<TextBox  Margin="10,3,15,0" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="150" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="*Last Name" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontSize="16"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}" Margin="0 12 8 0" Width="155"  ToolTip="Discard information entered and reset form" Background="#FF990B0B" Foreground="#FFECE9E9" BorderBrush="DarkRed">Cancel and Discard</Button>
```

Binding of my field works great and I have tied my button to a command that will call a method that I would want to reset the form:

```
public class CheckInViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ClearCommand { get; set; }

    private void ExecuteClear()
    {
        //reset form here  
    }
    public CheckInViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteClear);
    }
}
```

I know that I could probably just reset all the fields manually in the ExecuteClear method but this seems a bit clunky and error prone as in reality I have 40+ fields to handle.

I tried moving my bound fields to a completely separate model then making that model a property of my view model so I could re-instantiate it in the clear method but it does not seem to update the view when doing so. I imagine I must be missing a method call to unbind my last model and rebind to the new but I cannot figure out how to do it and cannot find any documentation on doing so.

Failed Attempt Example:

```
public class CheckInViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    public CheckInModel checkInModel { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ClearCommand { get; set; }

    private void ExecuteClear()
    {
        checkInModel = new CheckInModel();
    }

    public CheckInViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        checkInModel = new CheckInModel();
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteClear);
    }

}


public class CheckInModel : BindableBase
{

    private string _lastName
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); }
    }

}


<TextBox  Margin="10,3,15,0" Text="{Binding checkInModel.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="150" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="*Last Name" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" FontSize="16"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}" Margin="0 12 8 0" Width="155"  ToolTip="Discard information entered and reset form" Background="#FF990B0B" Foreground="#FFECE9E9" BorderBrush="DarkRed">Cancel and Discard</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your failed attempt, the property `checkInModel` does not raise `PropertyChanged` when you update it in `ExecuteClear`.

Change it to

```
private CheckInModel _checkInModel;
public ChechInModel CheckInModel
{
    get { return _checkInModel; }
    set { SetPropery( ref _checkInModel, value ); }
}

private void ExecuteClear()
{
    CheckInModel = new CheckInModel();
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding CheckInModel.LastName}"/>
<Button Content="Cancel and Discard" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: That was it, cannot believe I overlooked that. Thank your for catching it.